# Why doesn't my UICollectionView outline work?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios14

New in iOS 14, you can use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list` and NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot to make an automatic *outline* type of list. Apple demonstrated this in the WWDC videos, and they have a sample code project called Modern Collection Views that shows it too.

But when *I* do it, it doesn't work. I see the root item but when I tap it, it doesn't expand. Why not?

I have this problem *even when I copy and paste Apple's code into my own project*. I don't understand it. The very same code works in Apple's project but not in my project.

Here's a complete reproducible example. This is the *entire code* of the project. Tell me what's wrong with it!

**App Delegate**

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**Scene Delegate**

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let scene = scene as! UIWindowScene
        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        self.window!.rootViewController = CollectionViewController()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    init() {
        let config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .plain)
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: config)
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    private let cellId = "Cell"
    
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, String>! = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewListCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: self.cellId)
        
        let ds = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, String>(collectionView:self.collectionView) { cv, ip, s in
            let cell = cv.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cellId, for: ip) as! UICollectionViewListCell
            var contentConfig = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            contentConfig.text = s
            if ip.item == 0 {
                let opts = UICellAccessory.OutlineDisclosureOptions(style: .header)
                cell.accessories = [.outlineDisclosure(options: opts)]
            } else {
                cell.accessories = []
            }
            cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfig
            return cell
        }
        self.dataSource = ds
        
        var snap = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<String>()
        snap.append(["Pep"], to: nil)
        snap.append(["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"], to: "Pep")
        self.dataSource.apply(snap, to: "Dummy", animatingDifferences: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Fixed in Xcode 12 beta 4. The original example now works fine.

Your view controller is fine. You're doing everything correctly.

The problem is this line in the scene delegate:

```
self.window!.rootViewController = CollectionViewController()
```

For reasons that are completely obscure — Apple has failed to mention this anywhere — this feature works *only in a navigation controller interface.* Change that line to this:

```
self.window!.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CollectionViewController())
```

The outline will now spring to life.

[image]

Comment: FYI, outlines have nothing to do with navigation controllers; if you’re seeing expand/collapse not working in some cases, it’s just a bug in the iOS 14 beta.

Comment: @smileyborg F _Y_ I Nothing that costs me six hours of wasted time is “just” a bug. I did report this to Apple as soon as I figured it out, so if you’re on the team, please fix the bug. If you’re not on the team, I don’t see how you know that outlines have nothing to do with navigation controllers; my example, indeed, indisputably proves that they do, however improbable that may seem.

Comment: Please give it a try in the latest iOS 14 beta 4 released today.